# Java error: method in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I am just trying to call the methods to the main for each switch when it happens, but i just get the error message everytime i try to call any methods, not trying to return anything. ex. if the user enters a or A i want to call the add method to main

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    char character; 

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

    while (character != 'E' || character != 'e') 
    {

    System.out.println(" A:Addition \n S:Subtraction \n M:Multiplication \n D:Division \n R:Modulus \n E:exit");
    switch (character)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            System.out.println("your choice A");
            add(); 
            break; 

        case 's':
        case 'S':
            System.out.println("your choice S");
            subtraction();
            break; 

        case 'm':
        case 'M':
             System.out.println("your choice M");
             multiplication();
             break; 

        case 'd':
        case 'D':
             System.out.print("your choice D");
             division();
             break;

        case 'r':
        case 'R':
             System.out.println("your choice R");
             modulus();
             break;

        default: 
             System.out.println("Error: please enter a valid letter");
             break;

    } 
   }
 } 
public static void add(Scanner keyboard) 
{
    int a,b; 
    //get integer 1
    System.out.println("enter integer 1");
    a = keyboard.nextInt (); 

    //get integer 2
    System.out.println("enter integer 2"); 
    b = keyboard.nextInt();

     int total = a + b; 
    System.out.println(a + "plus" + b + "is" + total );
}
public static void subtraction(Scanner keyboard) 
{
    int a,b;

    //get integer 1
    System.out.println("enter integer 1");
    a = keyboard.nextInt (); 

    //get integer 2
    System.out.println("enter integer 2"); 
    b = keyboard.nextInt();
     int total = a-b;
    System.out.println(a + "minus" + b + "is " + total);
}
public static void multiplication(Scanner keyboard) 
{
    int a,b; 
    //get integer 1
    System.out.println("enter integer 1");
    a = keyboard.nextInt (); 

    //get integer 2
    System.out.println("enter integer 2"); 
    b = keyboard.nextInt();

    int total = a*b; 
    System.out.println(a + "times" + b + "is " + total);
}
public static void division(Scanner keyboard) 
{
    int a,b;

    //get integer 1
    System.out.println("enter integer 1");
    a = keyboard.nextInt (); 

    //get integer 2
    System.out.println("enter integer 2"); 
    b = keyboard.nextInt();
    int total = a/b;
    System.out.println(a + "divided" + b + "is " + total);
}
public static void modulus(Scanner keyboard) 
{
    int a,b;

    //get integer 1
    System.out.println("enter integer 1");
    a = keyboard.nextInt (); 

    //get integer 2
    System.out.println("enter integer 2"); 
    b = keyboard.nextInt();
    int total= a%b; 
    System.out.println(a + "modulus" + b + "is " + total);

    System.out.println("The program is terminating");
 }
```

}

Comment: What line are you getting this error on?

Comment: you define add to take in a `Scanner` object, but call it without any arguments...

Answer (score 1):

you're calling the method but you didn't include an argument

take a look at this.

```
public static void add(Scanner keyboard)
```

you have an argument, so you must include an argument when calling this method

so

you must call the method like this.

```
add(keyboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the method which takes Scanner as argument but you are calling the methods with no args.

Answer (score 0):

All the method you are using are supposed to receive a `Scanner` object while you pass no argument.

For example you call `add();` while it signature is

```
public static void add(Scanner keyboard)
```

Which is why you get the error.

Instead, use `add(keyboard)` and repeat the same for substraction, multiplication, division and modulus methods.

So that your `switch` would now look like

```
switch (character) {
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        System.out.println("your choice A");
        add(keyboard);
        break;

    case 's':
    case 'S':
        System.out.println("your choice S");
        subtraction(keyboard);
        break;

    case 'm':
    case 'M':
        System.out.println("your choice M");
        multiplication(keyboard);
        break;

    case 'd':
    case 'D':
        System.out.print("your choice D");
        division(keyboard);
        break;

    case 'r':
    case 'R':
        System.out.println("your choice R");
        modulus(keyboard);
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Error: please enter a valid letter");
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the arguments in the method call.

```
 case 'a':
    case 'A':
        System.out.println("your choice A");
        add(keyboard); // Add arguments.
        break;
```